# Inheritance across Projects in same solution

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance

I have two projects in my solution, Project A and Project B. I am trying to do a class override on one of the methods, and its not overriding for some reason (the virtual class in Project A is fired, but the override in Project B is not). Im sure everything is right in terms of Logic, but i dont know if this could be causing a problem because the inheritance is across two projects in a solution?

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is what i have tried sofar

**Class A in Project A**

```
public class classA
{
        public virtual bool CheckPermission()
        {
            return true;
        }


        public bool IsEnabled
        {
            get 
            {
                bool result = CheckPermission();

                _isEnabled = result;

                return _isEnabled; 
            }
        }
 }
```

**Viewmodel with override in Project B**

```
public class ViewModel : ClassA
{
    public override bool CheckPermission()
    {
       //Code logic in here
    }
}
```

Comment: Share your code where you create the instance of viewModel

Comment: CheckPermission call from ClassA is not going to ViewModel function]

Comment: Is there a typo in `classA` vs. `ClassA`?

Comment: @Sinatr I think the example you have provided is not proper. Even if you call the method v.CheckPermissions(); it will still call the overriden one.

Comment: Its called from IsEnabled, IsEnabled is called for each menuitem that is built up, and for every item i want to check if user has permissions to see the current menuitem. Thats where CheckPermission() is fired off to return a bool.

Comment: How do you instantiate the class? Show us.

Comment: @daryal, my bad, it should be `new` method for that.

Comment: Inheritance works the same whether the classes are in the same assembly or not. Your code example doesn't show related classes; `ViewModel` inherits a class named `ClassA`, but the only other class you show is named `classA` (**not** the same class as `ClassA`). In any case, without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a fix for the problem, which was actually a fault on my side. I was trying to inherit the class from a viewmodel which had no connection to the class. As a result what i was trying to do was impossible, to fix the issue i just did the operation directly in the class and passed some extra objects to the class needed for the operation.